# Error encountered while fetching: Unsupported URL protocol

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015's "Team Explorer" I have several Git repositories configured, all of them sync normally except one.

When I press "Pull" (or "Sync") I get this error:

[image: Failed to fetch from the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.]

... and this appears in the Output window:

> Error encountered while fetching: Unsupported URL protocol

How to pull?

Answer (score 0):

Any better solution is welcome, but meanwhile here is a workaround:

1. Push "Actions" and select "Open Command Prompt"

[image]

2. In the command prompt, type "git pull"

[image]